# Help Naming a Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a patient model and a client model. A patient can have many clients and a client can have many patients. I want to create a model for the association. What do I call it?

A client is a hospital or doctor's office. A Patient is someone who needs education from a hospital or doctors office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's a client? Is it a doctor of some kind?

How about `registrations` or `enrollments`?

You'd then have:

```
# client 
has_many :enrollments
has_many :patients, :through => :enrollments

# patient
has_many :enrollments
has_many :clients, :through => :enrollments
```

Comment: That sounds good. Would I do:

rails generate model Enrollment client_id:integer patient_id:integer active:boolean

Comment: Something like that, yeah. I don't really use the generators much, so I'm not sure if that'll generate the right model, but you'll want the enrollment model to `belongs_to client` and `belongs_to patient`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the conventions, then the names in the join table just need to be sorted alphabetically:

```
# create_clients_patients.rb
create_table "clients_patients", :id => false do |t|
  t.column "client_id", :integer, :null => false
  t.column "patient_id",  :integer, :null => false
end
```

Comment: This is assuming you're using a HMABTM relationship, which are deprecated in rails 3.1. You're better off using a has_many :through. Or if you call the model ClientsPatients, which would be a weird name.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to a model class you probably don't have to use a many-to-many
association but a:

```
has_many :through
```

association which you can name as you prefer.

The many-to-many association has only table naming convention (in your example clients_patients) because you don't need to access the cross table model directly.

Comment: I imagine the clients_patients model having an active boolean field on the association. In this case would I need a model or just a table?